# Get the latest version of a certificate from an Azure key vault in an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Creating an ARM template that needs to install an SSL certificate that is located inside of an Azure key vault. If I specify the certificate with the thumbprint, it works fine:

```
https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/web01-test-contoso-com/968bf207451149d3aceb390065af9d3a
```

But as a certificate is on a ticking clock, this hard-codes a dependency that can go stale into the ARM template. I would rather just specify the latest version (like it shows in the portal). However, I haven't found any documentation that shows how to do that or even mentions if it is possible.

I ran a couple of experiments using:

```
https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/web01-test-contoso-com
```

and

```
https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/web01-test-contoso-com/latest
```

But in both cases, I got the same error message:

```
message '{
   "error": {
     "code": "InvalidParameter",
     "message": "https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/web01-test-contoso-com/latest is 
 not a valid versioned Key Vault Secret URL. It should be in the format 
 https://<vaultEndpoint>/secrets/<secretName>/<secretVersion>.",
     "target": "certificateUrl"
   }
}'
```

So my question is: **How can I reference the certificate in a way that I get the latest version?**

For clarity, I am using the URL in the `secrets` section of the ARM template for a VM as follows, which gets the certificate from the Azure key vault and installs it into the Windows certificate store.

```
"secrets": [
    {
      "sourceVault": {
        "id": "[resourceId(parameters('keyVaultResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]"
      },
      "vaultCertificates": [
        {
          "certificateUrl": "https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/web01-test-contoso-com/latest",
          "certificateStore": "My"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

> **NOTE:** I would find it odd that you can specify the latest version of an OS to install, but you cannot specify to install the latest version of a certificate.

Comment: In the case this isn't possible, you could write a script that does this after ARM deployment.

Comment: In your pipeline, add a script that gets the latest version, and then pass it as a parameter into arm template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, contrary to what accepted answer says .
Define variable with secret's resource id like this, for example:

```json
"mySecretResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'), '/secrets/', 'my-secret-name')]"
```

then you can use it in your template as following:

```json
"certificateUrl": "[reference(variables('mySecretResourceId'), '2018-02-14').secretUriWithVersion]"
```

Comment: can be simplified: `resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', 'kvname', 'secret name')`. nice catch though

Comment: no, thats not true, it doesnt matter if the resource exist at all. resourceId() will always work

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct\easy way of doing this. Key Vault isnt exactly arm template friendly.

As juunas proposed you can write a script or use custom script extension to pull that data directly from key vault using managed service identity, for example.

Answer (score 0):

According to @4c74356b41's aswer I did it by my self in python script.

```
      data = json.loads(kv_auth_response.content)
      #
      ## Lets find youngest vesrion of certificate
      #
      if len(data['value']) > 0:
         for x in range(len(data['value'])):
             if x == 0:
                youngest = data['value'][x]['attributes']['exp']
                cert_url = data['value'][x]
             if data['value'][x]['attributes']['exp'] > youngest:
                youngest = data['value'][x]['attributes']['exp']
                cert_url = data['value'][x]
         arry = cert_url['id'].split('/')
...
         cert_version = arry[len(arry)-1]
```

At the first step of the loop, value of expire date is assigned to the "youngest" variable. In the next steps script compares expire date with it and assigns when the condition is met.
After loop script splits with "yougests" cert_url and assigns last part of array to "cert_version" variable.

Full view of this problem you can see in my script to BYOC for custom domain.
Link: https://github.com/przemika/azure-byoc-for-custom-domain/blob/master/start-byoc.py

Answer (score 0):

secretUriWithVersion worked. bicep equivalent script:

````
resource regionalKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource serviceFabricClusterCert 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-06-01-preview' existing = {
  name: certificateName
  parent: regionalKeyVault
}

vaultCertificates: [
{
certificateStore: certificateStore
certificateUrl: serviceFabricClusterCert.properties.secretUriWithVersion
} ```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).