# Install multiple versions of cert from KV in Azure Resource Manager (ARM)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-deployment

I'm using the `secrets` part of `osProfile` to install the certs I need from a given keyvault.

It looks something like this:

```
"secrets": [
    {
        "sourceVault": {
            "id": "[parameters('sourceVault')]"
        },
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "vaultCertificates",
                "count": "[length(variables('certificatesToInstall'))]",
                "input": {
                    "certificateStore": "[variables('certificateStore')]",
                    "certificateUrl": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('subscriptionId'), parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', parameters('keyVaultName'), variables('certificatesToInstall')[copyIndex('vaultCertificates')]), '2016-10-01').secretUriWithVersion]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Which worked fine. However now I need to make sure that more than one version of the same cert is installed on the machine (current one and the previous).

Things I've tried:

- Listing a certificate to get its versions directly from ARM. There seems to be no support for this for generic KV as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#list)
- Adding the full version of the cert to the `resourceId` function. This fails when deploying.

Any idea on how to reference previous versions of a cert inside ARM file?

Comment: you will need to pass the versions as parameters of the arm template i think

Comment: @Thomas nailed it - you have to pass them in, versions aren't exposed in the control plane.

Answer (score 0):

check the below code on how to define the  variable with secret's resource id

```json
"mySecretResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('keyVaultName'), '/secrets/', 'my-secret-name')]"
```

Then below code can be used in your template

```json
"certificateUrl": "[reference(variables('mySecretResourceId'), '2018-02-14').secretUriWithVersion]"
```

You can also go through this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60871345) which is having related discussions.

Also Check this [git hub](https://github.com/przemika/azure-byoc-for-custom-domain/blob/master/start-byoc.py) link.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The problem here is that I'm referencing **only** the latest version of the cert, and I want to reference at least the one before it as well so that I can make sure that I have them both on the machine while running.